# Django rest api and axios post request doesn't add new instance

Tags: reactjs, django

am trying to make a simple api where a user writes something in a field, presses a button and a new instance is added in the database. To do this I am using react and django rest framework.

App.js

```
const [name,setName] = useState('')
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

  function handleClick(e) {
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/', {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'X-CSRFToken': 'csrftoken'
      },
      data:{
        title: name,
        name: name
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type='text' value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>OK</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def home2(request):
    serializer = ItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('api/',views.home,name='home'),
path('post/',views.home2,name='home2'),
path('a/',views.home3,name='home3')
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'main',
    'corsheaders'
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

But when I press the button I get

manifest.json:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest.json 404 (Not Found) and

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. in javascript.

In django I get

"POST /post/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 Also I am using npm run build for javascript and manifest.json is in public folder.

React is inside django and the structure looks like this:

mysite
frontend
main
mysite
db.sqlite3
manage.py
Also when I try to make a new instance from "/post" (home2) I get in cmd

Method Not Allowed: /post/
"POST /post/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5588